# To find complete String is present or not...not sub string

Tags: php, string

If my str2 (variable) is java.
    still i get output :-value present.
    i want to search only complete string not sub string. Is their any 
    function which cheks for only complete string??

```
     $str2 ="javascript";

     $str1 ="abc def xyz in javascript ";

     if(stripos($str1,$str2) !== false) { 

        echo "value present";   

     }else{

     echo "noooo";

    }
```

Comment: every thing working fine the where you need help ?

Comment: yes its working fine.....if my $str2="java..my output is value present...but i don't want substring search

Comment: Something like `preg_match('/\bjavascript\b/', $str1)`?

Comment: There is no stand alone function, you will need regex.

Comment: @YabesNadar do you want check for string like $str2 ="javascript is awesome "; to ?

Comment: my both the variable($str1 & $str2) are dynamic. only thing i want is that it should not match sub string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search a string like this `$str2 ="javascript is awesome ";`

Then try below code

```
$str2 ="javascript is awesome";
$str1 ="abc def xyz in javascript ";
$filterKeys = explode(' ', $str2);
$regexp='';
foreach ($filterKeys as $word) {
    $word = trim($word);
    if ($word) {
        $regexp = $regexp . "$word|";
    }
}
$regexp = chop($regexp, '|');
preg_match("/\b($regexp)\b/i", $str1, $res);
if(!empty($res)) {
    echo "value present";
}else{
    echo "noooo";

}
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: Make sure to call [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on any user-provided values when dynamically creating a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here if you pass the full name in `$str` only it will return value present.

```
    $str1 ="abc def xyz in javascripts ";
    $array=explode(" ",$str1);
    $str='javascripts';
    if (in_array($str,$array)){
        echo "value present"; 
    }else{
        echo "noooo";
    }
```